# Authenticating access for multiple keychain items

Tags: wifi, security, keychain, airport

I am currently trying to access the WiFi credentials in the macOS keychain that are stored under the type "AirPort network password".

I can access each PSK directly with `security find-generic-password -a $SSID -w` for each SSID I know the name of, and as expected there is an OS security prompt for credentials to release the secret.

I can use find-generic-password to find a single item but for multiple items I need to provide user credentials for each and every secret.

I can use dump-keychain but this is very undesirable as many items are not WiFi passwords and still requires authentication for every secret.

Is there a method (either command line or via an API) to dump a filtered selection of the keychain (with a single authentication step preferably)?
Or is there a method for revealing multiple credentials similar to find-generic-password but for multiple items with a single authentication?